# Azure Media Services Error 400

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services, azure-webjobssdk

I am currently building an app and am trying to write a webjob to 
take an mp4file i have uploaded to blob storage and create an asset which i then can encode and prepare to stream using azure media services.

```html
public class Functions
    {
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        static string accName = "copied from portal ";
        static string accKey = "as above";
        static CloudMediaContext context = new CloudMediaContext(accName,accName);
        // Use the cached credentials to create CloudMediaContext.
        //static CloudMediaContext context = new CloudMediaContext(accName,accKey);
        public static void ProcessVideo(
        [QueueTrigger("videorequest")] VideoBlobInformation blobInfo,
        [Blob("{ProfileId}/{BlobName}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream input,
        [Blob("{ProfileId}/{BlobNameWithoutExtension}_stream.mp4")] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob)
        {
            VideoBlobInformation b = blobInfo;
            using (Stream output = outputBlob.OpenWrite())
            {
                ConvertAndPrepareVideo(b,input, output);
            }
            // Entity Framework context class is not thread-safe, so it must
            // be instantiated and disposed within the function.
            using (impulsevidContext db = new impulsevidContext())
            {
                //var id = blobInfo.ProfileId;
                //Video ad = db.Videos.Find(id);
                //if (ad == null)
                //{
                  //  throw new Exception(String.Format("AdId {0} not found, can't create thumbnail", id.ToString()));
                //}
                //ad.StreamUrl = outputBlob.Uri.ToString();
                //db.SaveChanges();
            }
            
        }
        public static void ConvertAndPrepareVideo(VideoBlobInformation info,Stream input, Stream output)
        {
            var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accnameofstorage", "storage account associated with azure media services"), true);
            //output all webjob input blobs into a container -mediacontroller- 
            var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var mediaBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("impfile");
            mediaBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            IAsset sourceAsset = context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id == info.VideoId).First();
        }
```

I am using a single storage account that i upload to.
i keep getting this error 400 no matter what i try caused by this line

```html
IAsset sourceAsset = context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id == info.VideoId).First();
```

which causes this log error

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessVideo ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
>    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AcsTokenProvider.<>c__DisplayClass47_2.b__0()
>    at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>    at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
>    at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AcsTokenProvider.RefreshToken()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AcsTokenProvider.GetAccessToken()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AcsTokenProvider.GetAuthorizationHeader()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.OAuth.OAuthDataServiceAdapter.AddAccessTokenToRequest(WebRequest request)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AzureMediaServicesClassFactory.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<GetAccountApiEndpoint>b__0()
>    at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.TransientFaultHandling.MediaRetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
>    at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AzureMediaServicesClassFactory.GetAccountApiEndpoint(OAuthDataServiceAdapter dataServiceAdapter, ServiceVersionAdapter versionAdapter, Uri apiServer, UserAgentAdapter userAgentAdapter, IWebRequestAdapter clientRequestIdAdapter)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AzureMediaServicesClassFactory.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.b__0()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.Cache`1.GetOrAdd(String key, Func`1 valueFactory, Func`1 expirationFactory)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AzureMediaServicesClassFactory.CreateAzureMediaServicesEndPoint(Uri azureMediaServicesEndpoint, MediaContextBase mediaContext)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AzureMediaServicesClassFactory..ctor(Uri azureMediaServicesEndpoint, CloudMediaContext mediaContext)
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.CloudMediaContext.get_MediaServicesClassFactory()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetCollection.<.ctor>b__2_0()
>    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetCollection.get_Queryable()
>    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.BaseCollection`1.get_Provider()
>    at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
>    at VideoProcess.Functions.ConvertAndPrepareVideo(VideoBlobInformation info, Stream input, Stream output)
>    at VideoProcess.Functions.ProcessVideo(VideoBlobInformation blobInfo, Stream input, CloudBlockBlob outputBlob)
>    at lambda_method(Closure , Functions , Object[] )
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`1.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments)
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.d__8.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__22.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__21.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__19.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__13.MoveNext()
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__13.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__10.MoveNext()

Comment: Are your file/container names too long?

Comment: nope the blob files are 8486c644-7ed7-4f63-bba2-a8dd60c10bb1.mp4 and the container names are id fields of this length f24d8371ef41e0b32ddc4da6f5aa84ef

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

context = new CloudMediaContext(new MediaServicesCredentials(
                            accName,
                            accKey));
should be set within the ConvertAndPrepareVideo method not outside